# Gmail Reputation problems

Tags: email, email-delivery

I am very dissatisfied about my email reputation, while I sending to gmail mailbox all mails are going to spam folder.

1. First I send 100 mails send out my domain reputation that time was High in gmail postmaster tools,
2. Gradually I increased the volume of mail , 100, 200, 500,1000,2500,...etc,, 8345 up to this.
3. After I checked out last time my gmail reputation was very bad, IP reputation also seems to be bad.

Please tell us how to increase a bad IP reputation to High reputation in Gmail.

I hope you can help me this problem out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your email reputation depends on open/click rate, bounces, spam complaints, unread deletes,...

Clean your recipients, check bounce processing work correctly, check you process feedback loop informations, try change the frequency of mails, if you are send for every action a mail try to send only a daily report

Comment: Tell me how to increase my gmail reputation , firstly it was high reputation in gmail postmaster, unfortunately I increased my email volume, later I check my reputation in google postmaster , it shows that reputation both IP & Domain decreases ( Low,  then Bad). Now it seems to be in Bad condition, tell me how to increase that in gradually ? All my emails were goes to spam folder.

Comment: Reputation changes are slowly, reduce the volume send only mails to recipients with activity. Check unsubscribe process working. What kind of mails you are sending?

Comment: I will send both promotional mails and our website newsletters. Tell me which time is the best time to send mails out. I usually send to gmail users, after noon. What time is the best?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your domain configured.
You should look if the following is correkt on your end:

- SFP protkoll in your DNS
- Your DKIM Signature in your DNS
- DMARC protokoll in your DNS
- All your E-mail adresses are valid and you are not on a spam listing.

Also if your are sending that many mails you should check that all the mails cotain an unsuscribe link like this .

I would recomend the use of one of the following tools to analyse the problem:

- [german] but way better https://www.mail-tester.com
- https://mxtoolbox.com/MXLookup.aspx